# Client terminate SSL Connection after server sends SERVER HELLO DONE

Tags: c#, ssl, connection, tls1.2

It is my first question on Stack Overflow, I'll do my best !

I have already read multiple document on how SLL/TLS connection works. I didn't found any clue of what is happening.

I am currently connecting to a server through SSL.
My OS is Windows 10. 
The server ask us a certificate which we provide.
Everything fine there. The SSL connection is established.

Now, when I try to establish the connection from my server, I receive a Web Exception ("The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.")
The server's OS is Windows Server 2012 R2.

I am pretty sure our server closes the connection (See attached picture at the bottom of the post).

### Code to load the certificate

```
        X509Certificate cubicCertificate;

        try
        {
            cubicCertificate = X509CertificateHelper.GetCertificate2FromStore(cubicCertificateThumbPrint);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            m_Log.Trace("Cubic Http client initialization - Could not load certificate");
            throw e;
        }

        var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cubicCertificate);
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        m_HttpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

        m_HttpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30); // 30 seconds timeout
        m_HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

### Code to send a request

```
        try
        {
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{cubicUrl}");
            requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
            m_Log.Trace($"URL - {m_HttpClient.BaseAddress}{url}");
            Task <HttpResponseMessage> task = m_HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            responseMessage = task.Result;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            var serializedException = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e);
            m_Log.Trace(serializedException);

            throw e;
        }
```

We have already verified

- That the certificate sent by the distant server is recognize by our server.
- That our server can load our certificate. (It is loaded from the Store)
- That our server can access the private key of our certificate

[image: Here is an sample of the communication (WireShark)]

Any help is welcome !

Comment: Is this c#?  It would help answerers to know a bit more...

Comment: Sign on to the server as the service account, open a browser, and attempt to navigate to the URL. The browser will prompt you for a client cert. If the connection works, it's a problem in your code; if it doesn't, the browser will tell you the specific reasons the negotiation failed.

Comment: Thanks, @JonhWu ! I tried in a web browser, I could see that the certificate request was answered by the client. The problem is must in IIS. Maybe it can't access the certificate or it's private key.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Yes it is c#, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the remote server is enforcing Client Authentication (see Certificate Request) and probably it does not trust your certificate.

Comment: Hi @Tom A. My client can not send the certificate. The server should accept it since it is the same I use on my machine.